# How to convert dict of dict to dict of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a nested dictionary like this:

```
{'name': {0: 'name1', 1: 'name2'}, 'age': {0: 'age1', 1: 'age2'}}
```

And I want to convert it to this:

```
{'name': [name2, name1], 'age': [age2, age1]}
```

I'm unsure of how to extract the values form the inner dictionaries, as well as sort them in the sense that if I were to sort the ages, the names would also be sorted in the same fashion. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the order matter? Would `{'name': [name1, name2], 'age': [age2, age1]}` also be acceptable output?

Comment: The order does matter, since name1 has age age1 etc.

Comment: So what matters is that the order is the same everywhere, but it's fine if `name2` is listed before `name1`?

Comment: you might be better off re formating your dict to keep the associated name and age together. Keeping two dict entries in sync is a bit error prone. `{'name1': age1, 'name2': age2}` might be a better format.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try dictionary comprehension, if your dictionary is called `d`:

```
# Python 2:
{k:d[k].values() for k in d}
# Python 3:
{k:list(d[k].values()) for k in d}
```

Which returns:

```
{'age': ['age1', 'age2'], 'name': ['name1', 'name2']}
```

Comment: **Note**: You should not expect the values in each dictionary will be in the same key order (OP's requirement). "The order does matter, since name1 has age age1 etc." Dictionary order has not been specified anywhere.

Comment: This answer along with Dom Weldon's below is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are not ordered so you will need to sort the dictionary keys to ensure they align with the indices you want in your list.

```
d = {k: [v[i] for i in sorted(v.keys(), reverse=True)] for k, v in data.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one functional way:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = {'name': {0: 'name1', 1: 'name2'}, 'age': {0: 'age1', 1: 'age2'}}

d = {k: list(map(itemgetter(1), sorted(v.items()))) for k, v in data.items()}

# {'age': ['age1', 'age2'], 'name': ['name1', 'name2']}
```